# Displaying dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display some text but the text is going to change a lot and I need for it to be editable. I know I can use from input but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDN has a nice [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) and MSDN - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for contenteditable

```
<div id="toEdit" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="doSomething(this.id);"></div>
```

`doSomething` function can manipulate the data (store/send whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax query and change the value of the text area.. using that.. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

you can put a little button (or use even the text itself as a handler) so that when a user clicks, you add the input to change the text using ajax.